# Optimize Node.js Script with MongoDB when retrieving large numbers of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata, gridfs

So I have this script, that the main objective is to migrate all the attachments to a GridFS Bucket:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Grid = require('mongodb').GridFSBucket;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var process = require('process');

var collection = 'bond';
var dir = 'C:/Users/Fernando/Documents/MigratedData/' + collection + "/";
var filePath = '';
var fileName = '';


// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
  if(err) return console.dir(err);

  console.log("CONNECTED SUCESSFULLY");
  var db = client.db('GO2_Alpha');
  var bucket = new Grid(db, { bucketName: collection});

  console.log("Executing Query...");
  db.collection(collection).find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", err);
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log("Searching for all [", collection, "] orders...");
    }

    result.forEach(order => {
      if(order.attachments != []) {
        order.attachments.forEach((file, i) => {
          var cleanInternalCode = order.internalCode.replace(/\//g, '');
          fileName = cleanInternalCode + "#A" + i;
          filePath = path.join(dir + fileName);

          downloadFiles(file.raw);
          saveFiles(bucket);
          console.log("Attachment [", fileName, "] downloaded.");
        });
      }
    })
    console.log("Operation Ended");
  })
});

function downloadFiles(fileReceived) {
  fs.appendFile(filePath, fileReceived, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}

function saveFiles(targetBucket) {
  fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .pipe(targetBucket.openUploadStream(fileName))
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("Some error occured: ", err);
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
    });
}
```

But it takes too long to get all the information that I need, how can improve this code?
I need to retrieve all attachments from mongoDB and then use GridFS to save them in buckets.

Sometimes, when I run the script, is throws an error saying that: 
`Error: EMFILE: too many open files`

When I search for `ulimit -a` in the console, it retrieves this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 254
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

So I used the follow command line: `ulimit -n 2048` to change that limit, but it stills throwing the same error.
How can I optimize the max that I can, so it takes less time and doesn't throw this kind of errors?

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards.